# Shifted From Command Prompt to Net Beans

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

I have just installed Netbeans IDE 7.0 and tried to run my project (which executes fine when I run with traditional method using command prompt) based on image processing but applet viewer says `start: applet not initialized` whereas compiling (`build` task in Netbeans) is successful.

Here I am attaching 2 relevant Java files while whole project has 3-4 more java files for image rendering.

```
/* 
* <applet code=ImageFilterDemo width=350 height=450> 
* <param name=img value=strawberry.jpeg> 
* <param name=filters value="Grayscale+Invert+Contrast+Blur+Sharpen"> 
* </applet> 
*/  
import java.applet.*;  
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import java.util.*;  
import java.awt.image.* ;  
public class ImageFilterDemo extends Applet implements ActionListener {  

Image img;  
PlugInFilter pif;  
Image fimg;  
Image curImg;  
LoadedImage lim;  
Label lab;  
Button reset;  
Button histograph;  

Dimension d;  
static int iw, ih;  
int pixels[];  
static int w, h,just;  
static int hist[] = new int[256];  
static int max_hist = 0;  

public void init() {  
setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
Panel p = new Panel();  
add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);  
reset = new Button("Reset");  
histograph = new Button("Histograph");  
reset.addActionListener(this);  
histograph.addActionListener(this);  
p.add(reset);  
p.add(histograph);  
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(getParameter("filters"), "+");  
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {  
Button b = new Button(st.nextToken());  
b.addActionListener(this);  
p.add(b);  
}  
lab = new Label("");  
add(lab, BorderLayout.NORTH);  
img = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"strawberry.jpeg");  
lim = new LoadedImage(img);  
add(lim, BorderLayout.CENTER);  

d = getSize();  
w = d.width;  
h = d.height;  
try {  
//img = getImage(getDocumentBase(), getParameter("img"));  
MediaTracker t = new MediaTracker(this);  
t.addImage(img, 0);  
t.waitForID(0);  
iw = img.getWidth(null);  
ih = img.getHeight(null);  
pixels = new int[iw * ih];  
PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, iw, ih,  
pixels, 0, iw);  
pg.grabPixels();  
} catch (InterruptedException e) { };  
for (int i=0; i<iw*ih; i++) {  
int pii = pixels[i];  
int r = 0xff & (pii >> 16);  
int g = 0xff & (pii >> 8);  
int b = 0xff & (pii);  
int y = (int) (.33 * r + .56 * g + .11 * b);  
hist[y]++;  
}  
for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {  
if (hist[i] > max_hist)  
max_hist = hist[i];  
}  
}  

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {  
String a = "";  
try {  
a = (String)ae.getActionCommand();  
if (a.equals("Reset")) {  
lim.set(img);  
lab.setText("Normal");  
}  
else if(a.equals("Histograph")){  
lab.setText("Histo_graph");  
just=1;  
lim.repaint();  
}   
else {  
pif = (PlugInFilter) Class.forName(a).newInstance();  
fimg = pif.filter(this, img);  
lim.set(fimg);  
lab.setText("Filtered: " + a);  
}  
repaint();  
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  
lab.setText(a + " not found");  
lim.set(img);  
repaint();  
} catch (InstantiationException e) {  
lab.setText("could't new " + a);  
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {  
lab.setText("no access: " + a);  
}  
}  
}  


// 2nd file
import java.awt.*;  

public class LoadedImage extends Canvas {  
Image img;  

public LoadedImage(Image i) {  
set(i);  
}  

void set(Image i) {  
MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);  
mt.addImage(i, 0);  
try {  
mt.waitForAll();  
} catch (InterruptedException e) { };  
img = i;  
repaint();  
}  


public void paint(Graphics g) {  
if (img == null) {  
g.drawString("no image", 10, 30);  
}  

else if(ImageFilterDemo.just==1){  
int x = (ImageFilterDemo.w - 256) / 2;  
int lasty = ImageFilterDemo.h - ImageFilterDemo.h * ImageFilterDemo.hist[0] / ImageFilterDemo.max_hist;  
for (int i=0; i<256; i++, x++) {  
int y = ImageFilterDemo.h - ImageFilterDemo.h * ImageFilterDemo.hist[i] / ImageFilterDemo.max_hist;  
g.setColor(new Color(i, i, i));  
g.fillRect(x, y, 1, ImageFilterDemo.h);  
g.setColor(Color.red);  
g.drawLine(x-1,lasty,x,y);  
lasty = y;  
}  
ImageFilterDemo.just=0;  
}   
else {  
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);  
}  
}  

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {  
return new Dimension(img.getWidth(this), img.getHeight(this));  
}  
public Dimension getMinimumSize() {  
return getPreferredSize();  
}  
}
```

Is there any changes we have to make in settings or coding when we change from running from traditional command prompt, to Netbeans?

Comment: Is there any changes we have to make in settings or coding when we run from traditional command prompt to net beans...

Comment: is there any output in the console when you run it in netbeans?

Comment: By the way, this isn't a forum - it's a (community editable) Q&A website.  That might seem like a pedantic distinction to make, but it does mean there's less focus on discussion on more on providing canonically correct answers to questions.  In particular, you shouldn't post more questions or "answers" in response to others, but rather edit your original question to reflect the updates.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new project in NetBeans and have a look at how it works with Applets by default.

If you add an Applet to your project (new File -> Swing GUI forms -> JApplet Form)

have a look at the init code that is generated for you

```
@Override
    public void init() {
        /* Create and display the applet */
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I would think that your code would need a block like this to able to do a 'File Run' or 'Project Run' in NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your applet in javaWeb if i remember correctly.

```
Properties -> Run -> Run with Java Web Start.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this little tutorial helps, http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html

Comment: When you are having trouble getting your own applets to work, it is probably best not to offer advice (even links) to others.  After all, if you are following that advice to the letter yourself, it is obviously not working.